# how to add form to application.html.erb page ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm quite new to ruby and I'm trying to put the form to add a new post to the "application.html.erb" page.

Somehow I can't get it to work by just copying the code from the "app/views/things/_form.html.erb" page, and also I can't seem to get it to work by copying the code from the "app/views/things/new.html.erb" page.

If I do that I get the error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

The error points towards:

```
<%= form_for(@thing) do |f| %>
```

This is a code that I find in the "app/views/things/_form.html.erb" page.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? To be honest, I don't even know where to start looking for the answer.

Comment: by the way , why do you need to move that code to application.html.erb ? I mean what's wrong with it in its place ?

Comment: Well I want to try and make a webpage that shows both the form which adds a post to my database, and also shows all of the posts as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at ruby on rails MVC model first, and also go through a basic tutorial. Just a quick review of you question:

1. application.html.erb is usually in the `layout` folder of rails,
   it's job is to provide a root template/layout for the whole project if not specified.
   usually you **don't** want to put any code that is not commonly
   needed by all pages.
2. the reason it is giving you the error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` is because, the helper method `form_for` is expecting the controller to provide a `@thing` to the view file `application.html.erb`, in your case, it is obvious that `@thing` is not exist in your controller or your `ApplicationController`.

Comment: there is `ApplicationController`

Comment: Thanks! I guess I am editing in the wrong place then, somehow I thought of the application.html.erb as my overall "home" page. But I guess I should create a new page as my normal "website base" or "index" that loads the application itself?

Comment: it really depends on you, for example, you can create a `HomePageController` with `index` action to show your home page. MVC model is pretty flexible, but in rails, there are many conventions, if you follow them, it makes your life much easier. For example, you can try `rails generate scaffold User name:string`. this will generate a scaffold completely following rails convention, you can take a look at how it set up `routes.rb`, `controller`, `views` and `model`

Answer (score 0):

The `@thing` should be initialized in your controller. I suppose you've got a `things_controller.rb` that has a `new` action in it. In this action, controller should initialize `@thing` and therefore it is visible in `app/views/things/new.html.erb`.

You really shouldn't put forms in `application.html.erb`, but just to make the error disappear, you could do

```
<%= form_for(Thing.new) do |f| %>
```

(assuming you've got a `Thing` model in `app/models/thing.rb`).

This way you'll initialize an instance of `Thing` right in your `application.html.erb` view.

Comment: in my opinion the way you're giving shouldn't even be mentioned, the right way should be mentioned instead